# What should be a safe, secure, correct server side password validation response?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, security, response

I am trying to implement a page where the staff can login and add, modify, update work cases.

I have a select list with data (staff names) loaded from a DB. In this DB I have the basics, username, id, password, email.

The default value for the select list/box is "-"; when it changes, a form pops up asking to enter the password for the SELECTed staff member.

With jQuery, I send the id, user and password (plain text) to the server. In the php file, 
I escape (`mysqli_real_escape_string`) ALL three variables and hash (`md5($salt.$varname)`) the password.

I the query the mysql DB with `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$escapedId."' AND name='".$escapedName."'`.

After checking if `num_rows==1` and if `$hashedPasswd==$mysqlresult['passwd']` I do:

```
$serverResponse->reponses['passwdOK']=true;
echo json_encode($serverResponse);
```

So, my two questions are: Should I change the query to include the password (...`WHERE passwd=$hashedPasswd...`) and if the response I am sending/returning to the JS file is OK (by OK I mean if it is safe, secure). If the response is NOT secure/safe, what would be a correct server response.

P.S. I do not want to reload or redirect to another page, in fact, if the password is OK 
I want to unlock/enable some controls on the already loaded page.

Comment: Please format the code in your post.

Comment: I hope you’re still checking the user’s authorization for those locked/disabled controls when they trigger some action on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your approach:

- Nowadays, MD5 is completely unsuitable for password hashing because it is way too fast and can therefore be easily brute-forced. Use bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF instead.
- I assume you are using a global salt for all your passwords? If so, this leaves your hashed passwords vulnerable for a rainbow table attack. Instead you should randomly generate a salt for each seperate user and store these in your database. Libraries implementing bcrypt or such generally already do the salting for you.
- Escaping each query parameter manually and then conatenating them with partial queries is very sensitive for errors that could lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. It is highly recommended to use [Prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements) instead. In PHP, this is often done through the PDO framework.
- Sending passwords over plaintext is dangerous, so you really should use HTTPS so traffic between the user and your server is encrypted. However, this will require you to have a certificate. You could use a self-signed certificate, in which case each client that can access your app will need to be configered to accept it, or let it be signed by a [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Authority), which you'll need to pay for. If you do not want to or simply can not use HTTPS, it is a good idea to recommend your users to not log in from open wi-fi networks and to not use the same password for your app as they use for other things such as their e-mail account. You could also try hashing passwords on the client-side (and again on the server side; do not forget to also use random salts here); this will not protect you from Man-In-The-Middle attacks but can prevent passive listeners (which are more common) from snooping passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good, but you should remember, that any communication between browser and server should be encrypted (https). If not, anyone between server and browser would be able to read all data given by user (login, password).

I don't think that your query is the best choice for the performance. What is the purpose of selecting data if password doesn't match the password in database. Query shoud be "WHERE `id` = id AND `password` = 'hash'.

If password is OK, database would send you user data, if not you won't get anything beside FALSE. I'm not pro skill mysql expert, but as far as I know it is better solution.

And, what's more. You don't need to escape hash. If you get anything from md5() function it is already "escaped".

Anyway, I would make it that way:

```
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
$pass = md5(SALT.$_POST['pass']);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `user_table` WHERE `id` = $id AND `password` = $pass;
```

Comment: Imo, this still isn't safe. Best bet, prepared statements.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: What could ever possibly be unsafe about it? The real probem is that it's not valid PHP syntax.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their prompt responses.I do not think I am ready for prepared statements/PDO since I know NOTHING about them. I, however, have worked with self-signed certificate and https and I think I will move towards this direction.

The reason I asked for this question is because I have seen (with firebug) a couple of sites where the userid and password are NOT sent hashed (banks, bankofamerica -> plaintext but buried in an XML, pornsites) (I always go to banks or pornsites when trying to imitate good security, do not know it is a good idea).

Comment: I am not completely clear about my server response. Is it OK to just response with a JSON object and a variable set to true?

I have also noticed that MOST login forms always redirect to another page, is this because redirecting is more secure?

Comment: By the way, I do use a global salt, how could a randomly generated salt be used? Should it be generated on the client side and sent to the server? Should something like the last generated salt be stored in the DB? Sorry for the many questions.

Comment: Whenever a user specifies a new password (when registering or changing passwords), you should generate a random salt on the server side, use it to hash this password and store a combination of salt + hashed passwords in the database. Later, whenever this user tries to log in, you retrieve this users' salt and hash from the DB; then you use this salt to hash the password he/she logged in with and match hashes to determine whether the password was OK.

Comment: However, I would not recommend doing this yourself. Instead, use a library (based on bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF) with seperate 'createPasswordHash' and 'validatePassword' functions and let these take care of the salting and password matching for you.